# How to send AJAX callback to my own server/php file

Tags: php, ajax

I want to fire up a function when a user hits the button publishes the site with an ajax call and we're having a hard time correcting or fixing this error (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ).

Trying this solution: We should be sending the AJAX call back to your own server/php file. This PHP file then should send that API call back to Duda directly. The flow should be:

```
 function publish_site() {
    var site_name = $(".site_name").val();
    var url = 'https://mywebsite.com/home/site/'+site_name;
    $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            data:{site_name:$(".site_name").val()},//Get Account Information
            dataType:'jsonp',
            url:'publish-site.php',
            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

               $('#publish-btn').toggleClass("btn-primary"); // Revert back to default primary
               $("#publish-btn").html("Publish"); // Change text of button    
               $('.url-here').append('<a href='+url+'>Click here to redirect</a>');
               console.log("Completed: "+textStatus);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                 console.log("Error: "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                console.log("Success: "+textStatus);

            },


    });//ajax end
    }//function publish_site end


    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#publish-btn").click(function(e){
       $("#publish-btn").toggleClass("btn-primary"); // Switch to default grey
       $("#publish-btn").html("Publishing"); // Change text of button    

      publish_site();
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't see how you can get a CORS error when you post to `publish-site.php`. And are you really sending jsonp back?

Answer (score 0):

are u trying this code in your local server then you should download this google chrome extension and enabled it

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

or

if it's in your server then please and are you using php then place the this link in your php file

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

if you need more information about this then open this link

http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: thank you mate but , we are also implementing it on our live server .. and we are not sure how to allow origin through ajax  . to connect through the other server is done by php and we are just calling the php to publish site through ajax then redirect  . note ( the redirect is happening under our php file) is that okay or it should be done through ajax ?

Comment: hey mate are u not understand, what the things is going in server it's allow the access origin,but in local server you should enabled and other things is that it's not redirect you can see the link url and it fill the content you should just use this things in other php variable or any file what ever your flow man. need any help i am available